# How do I create a file that only contains functions in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, function

I want to make a file that contains useful functions for my project. Well, I know that I can define a function inside my class implementation. But I don't really get it... I mean: I don't want to create a "class", just functions. Or are functions always part of a class? My objective-c knowledge is pretty limited, and my nice big book on objective-c does mention them, but does not explain how to implement them stand-alone.

Answer (score 4):

Organize your code in plain old C style:

- a header file (.h) containing all function declarations.
- a body file (.c) containing all function bodies.

Include your header file wherever you need one of your functions.

Let Xcode manage compilation and link.

Comment: How would a header declaration of a function look like? Just the same way as a method declaration?

Comment: The syntax is a bit different but the principle is similar. for instance, the declaration of fopen function is: FILE *fopen(const char *FILE, const char *MODE);

Answer (score 4):

Because Objective-C is a superset of C, you can do this in the normal c way, in that you define your functions in a header file, which you include wherever you want to use them, then implement them in the .c file.

I'd probably implement them as class methods on a class in order to namespace them, and prevent any accidental collisions, though.

Comment: When they're part of a class, then other objects don't have to instantiate that class in order to use the functions, right?

Comment: If you implement them as class methods, then no. Just do this:

    [MyClass somefunction];